# Python: For every 2 items in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The default `for` loop only iterates through each item at a time. How can I make it so I can iterate through every *2* items?

Comment: Do you mean every other item, every non-overlapping pair, or every overlapping pair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the slice notation:

```
for item in items[::2]:
   print(item)
```

If you want to iterate *pairwise* every 2 items, you can do this:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(items[::2], items[1::2]):
   print(item1, item2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
for item in items[::2]:
   <your_code>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for idx, item in enumerate(items):
    if idx % 2 == 1:
        // do something
```

Comment: Why not use the slice notation? `items[::2]` would be more Pythonic

Comment: Yes, if we don't need to access the index, that might be a better way.

Comment: @zdimension: There is sometimes a reason to not copy (even half of) the input.

Answer (score 0):

The following will iterate over every two items:

```
for i in range(0,20,2):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a list. Then 
You can use the slice notation

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in data[::2]:
...     print(I)
```